# Is it even possible to achieve this?

Tags: java

I believe this has something to do with reflection, but anyways,

I want to prompt the user to enter the name of a valid Java class (say Scanner or String or whatever) at run-time and then create an object corresponding to that class.

Can I do this? If yes, how?

Comment: **Yes**. But what do you want to do with it, once you've created it?

Comment: I just want to know how to do this. Curious.

Comment: You could do it with a switch statement. Or an if else statement. Have some value read from standard in correspond with some constructor call.

Comment: @bpgeck: Not really. There may be hundreds of classes in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
Class.forName(yourClassName).newInstance();
```

If the class has a specific constructor (taking a String for example), you can also do something like:

```
Class.forName(yourClassName).getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance("somestring");
```